# can not delete create passive sell offer

Tags: stellar-sdk, operations

in stellar docs
(https://developers.stellar.org/docs/start/list-of-operations/#create-passive-sell-offer)

- Amount of selling being sold. Set to 0 if you want to delete an existing offer.

if I set amount to 0, then result always return op_malformed.
even in https://laboratory.stellar.org/ I cant set amount to 0 in create passive sell offer

below is response

response =
{
"extras": {
"envelopeXdr": "AAAAAH+aowOsrW2KZU6rtz4uAcwaOYQNkB726CIRsEPd1t5uAAAAZAAMj/4AAAATAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAEMTM0NAAAAAEAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAABVVNEAAAAAACUUJEYrqmtIdoKeKqlyH/u+0DQKpVrx8N0khr+U2AhJgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAd3W3m4AAABAuULyRaJYsZw0uGEVnIOPOdoiR+q9Ou/vwO3nLRNU/upypx3n190QyHQ628k6MAd9xVex2IU8Gh2mU/FQNRPUDQ\u003d\u003d",
"resultCodes": {
"operationsResultCodes": [
"op_malformed"
],
"transactionResultCode": "tx_failed"
},
"resultXdr": "AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAD/////wAAAAA\u003d"
},
"rateLimitLimit": 0,
"rateLimitRemaining": 0,
"rateLimitReset": 0
}

how can i delete that?

Answer (score 2):

Docs looks to be wrong (I opened a PR to fix them), to delete offers you have to use one of `ManageSellOfferOp` or `ManageBuyOfferOp` and specify both the `offerID` of that offer you're trying to delete and set the price to 0.